# Get back vs go back vs come back vs arrive vs return

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

When you read the meanings of these 5 verbs they kinda seem like synonyms although they are not,here are their meanings from long man dictionary:

> 1)**get back**:to return to a place
>
> 2)**go back**:to return to a place that you have just come from
>
> 3)**come back**:to return to a particular place or person
>
> 4)**arrive**:to get to the place you are going to
>
> 5)**return**:to go or come back to a place where you were before

My question is how can I use them and what are their exact differences:forexample which of these five sentences is correct?(considering that you are talking about your daily routine)

> 1)I go to university at 7 O'clock in the morning then I **get back** home at 3 o'clock in the afternoon.
>
> 2)I go to university at 7 O'clock in the morning then I **go back** home at 3 o'clock in the afternoon.
>
> 3)I go to university at 7 O'clock in the morning then I **come back** home at 3 o'clock in the afternoon.
>
> 4)I go to university at 7 O'clock in the morning then I **arrive**  home at 3 o'clock in the afternoon.
>
> 5)I go to university at 7 O'clock in the morning then I **return** home at 3 o'clock in the afternoon.

Answer (score 9):

They're not quite synonymous, although in this context some of them are interchangeable.

1. **Get back** refers to the arrival. If you *got back* home at 3AM, it means you entered your home at 3AM, even if you've left earlier.
2. **Go back** refers to the departure. If you *went back* home at 3AM, it means you left the place you had been at previously at 3AM, but arrived later, or even not at all.
3. **Come back** refers to the arrival just like *get back*, with a caveat - if someone tells you to *come back* it means they're at the place they want you to be in. So your mom could tell you to *come back* home if she's waiting for you, but a friend you're out with would tell you to *get* or *go* back home.
4. **Arrive** is more or less the same as *get back* in this context. Maybe with a little more emphasis on the journey - to me, *arriving* somewhere seems like a more arduous process than just *getting* somewhere. (Also, you can *arrive* somewhere you haven't been yet).
5. **Return** in this context is somewhat ambiguous, although I'd read it as referring to the arrival rather than the departure. It's also more formal than the first three.

Comment: In example 2 shouldn`t it be: you left the place you had been at previously at 3AM? something that happens before something else in the past = past perfect?

Comment: Good question :) I think your sentence would mean something different than what I wanted to say ("I had been at this place at 3AM on some day long ago, and I left it yesterday at an unspecified time" rather than "I have been at this place for a length of time and then I left it at 3AM"), but I'm actually not so sure now that I look at it.

Comment: Do you mean that I can't use come back to talk about my self like example 3 forexample another person like my mom your my friends should tell me that?or no I can use it but the meaning that it conveys is some thing like I have reached my house?

Comment: @anonymous you absolutely can use it to talk about yourself. It's when you're talking to someone that it's not quite interchangeable with "get back" - you can't use it to send somebody off, only to call someone to where you are.

Answer (score -1):

> **get back**
>   **come back**
>   **arrive** *(usually has a qualifier to not be ambiguous)*

These are from the perspective of the *future destination*, travelling *from*.

> **go back**
>   **return**

These are from the perspective of the *current location*, travelling *to*.

In general, it does not matter if you are at the *destination*.

> My Mother told me to "**Come back** home".
>   *Your Mom is at home, you are not*
>
> I **go back** to work tomorrow.
>   *You are not at work*.
>
> "**Go back** to where you came from!"
>   *They are telling you to go "there"*.
>
> I **arrive** home at 6:00 PM.
>   *You could be anywhere, but you will be home after 6:00 PM*

There are exceptions

> "[**Get back** to where you once belonged](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6gKe9Fr2ok&t=0m26s)" - popularized by The Beatles

has the same mening as "***go back***".

Comment: "to get back", "to come back" and "to arrive" can be used in any tense, not only future (eg I came back yesterday)