# come/get back to work

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

"I want you to come back to work. We really miss you."

"I want you to get back to work. We really miss you."

Are these interchangeable? Or does "get" give another meaning?

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/156527/get-back-vs-go-back-vs-come-back-vs-arrive-vs-return

Comment: More naturally: "**return** to work."

Answer (score 2):

The way I interpret the two sentences is, "come back to work" means you are not at work (maybe you are sick or traveling), and you are told to **go back to that specific** workplace. Get back to work sounds like not motion, but you are doing a **different activity other than work**.

In a nutshell, "come" is for a change in location and "get" is for a change in activity.